# Mongorestore from oplog miss some records

Tags: mongodb

We did a dump of a mongo oplog and now try to restore it on another server with :

```
mongorestore -vvvvv --authenticationDatabase admin -u mongoUser -p --oplogReplay --filter '{"o._id": ObjectId( "54566b2856a34e1831157660" )}' dump/
```

We went down to only 1 record in filter to test, but without filter nothing get imported at all with same output.

We dumped from a single Replica set and try to import into a fresh sharded cluster.

This produce the following output :

```
Enter password: 
2014-11-05T15:02:55.596+0100 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
2014-11-05T15:02:55.596+0100 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2014-11-05T15:02:55.597+0100 connected to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2014-11-05T15:02:55.597+0100 connected connection!
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2014-11-05T15:02:55.857+0100 drillDown: dump
2014-11-05T15:02:55.857+0100     Replaying oplog
     file size: 21413184554
2014-11-05T15:02:58.000+0100        Progress: 3905443976/21413184554    18% (bytes)
2014-11-05T15:03:01.001+0100        Progress: 8027986469/21413184554    37% (bytes)
2014-11-05T15:03:04.000+0100        Progress: 11157894758/21413184554   52% (bytes)
2014-11-05T15:03:07.001+0100        Progress: 14340379265/21413184554   66% (bytes)
2014-11-05T15:03:10.000+0100        Progress: 17890791357/21413184554   83% (bytes)
2820163 objects found
1 objects processed
2014-11-05T15:03:12.945+0100 Applied 1 oplog entries out of 1 (0 skipped).
```

Seems good, but the record does not appear in the db... What are we doing wrong ?

Beside, we are running oplogreplay from uberVU to keep synced with the old db. This is working fine, records keep popping in new db. But we had to specify --skipIndexes cuz a previous index is now a shard key

Comment: An oplog does not necessarily create a document. Is there a reason why you don't dump the whole database?

Comment: my bad, missed to mention that point. We dumped the database + oplog first and reimported it. As this take few days to complete and our current server only have like 20 hours of oplog, we dumped oplog a few times for later import. Once the big dump import completed, we launched some oplogreplay to keep a live sync. After that we tried to mongorestore the few dumped oplog to fill the gap. And those are failing. So our server has now a hole of the initial restore duration.

Comment: Mongorestore and mongodump aren't suitable for large collections / databases. They are notoriously slow. I will write an answer with more proper approaches later this day.

Comment: Thanx you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to solve this by using other tools than mongodump / mongorestore. Going with the dropbox hydra project (https://github.com/dropbox/hydra) went much faster and smoother to copy the whole database and keep in sync our new cluster.

Dunno if it's the tools Markus was going to suggest in comments, but they work fine :)

Still no clues why mongo tools does not do the job here. They take 5 days to fail. Hydra took less than a day to success...